# Issues with training a tensorflow recommender retrieval model using changing user/items pairs

Tags: tensorflow, recommendation-engine

I have an issue with user/item pairs training data when training a [tensorflow retrieval model](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/basic_retrieval).

I have following two datasets:

1. Pairs of user/items over a specific period. This represents an item which the user has viewed at a point in time.
2. A complete list of items for that same period.

The problem I have is that in a specific period, some items were added and removed at certain times. Which meant, depending on the time, users were only able to view part and not all available items.

For example, let's say you have the following activity of the user and items over a period of time. For this example assume that item_A, item_B and item_C are a similar type of product.

```
Jan 1  - item_A - listed
Jan 10 - item_B - listed  
Jan 10 - user_1 views item_A and item_B
Jan 11 - item_C - listed
Jan 13 - item_A - removed
Jan 14 - user_2 views item_B and item_C
```

In the example above item_A was not available at the time user_2 viewed items B and C, so it counts item_A as a negative sample, which is not correct.

Is there any particular way to handle these types of issues when creating training data?

Answer (score 0):

try to append the items from the real-time datasets (1. A complete list of items for that same period. 2. and from Pairs of user/items over a specific period. Which represents an item that the user has viewed at a point in time.) to a new list as an available_items. even though the item is currently not available, you can get a list of all available items. access to the user must be given to the newly created list. you can also add a column as availability (if to show the user the availability at the current time). This MAY help you.

```
l_avail=[]#to get all available items where user can see all the available items
l=[]#to update the availabiility
import pandas as pd
  
# Define a dictionary containing items data
data = {'items': ['A', 'B', 'C']}#list of available items l_avail
        
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  
# Declare a list that is to be converted into a column
availability = [0, 1, 1, 0] 
df['Availability'] = address

print(df)
# to do list and remove to respective list
def LISTED(x):
    l.append(x)
    l_avail.append(x)
def REMOVE(x):
    l.remove(x)
```

this is a rough code that may help you to get my idea. :)

Comment: add the item  to l_avail, if item not in l_avail

Comment: thank you for you response. I think I understand what you are proposing, however, I will need to adapt this to the tensorflow retrieval model. It uses a two tower network approach. So I think I could possibly add a feature of "availability" to the items model in the two tower architecture. Will give it a try and see if it works. thanks